# Why is it my toString has error?

Tags: java, tostring

Why does my `toString` method have an error?

```
String score1 = Arrays.toString(newGame.top3Score[0]);
```

I am trying to take out the array value then convert them into strings.

Comment: Line gives compile error and you are asking why. You have to put some effort to resolve the problem before raising question here.

Comment: this question must be edited. Java tag must be added, and Code must be transformed from the title to the question body

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.toString` is expecting an array, yet you are only passing one element, try using:

`Arrays.toString(newgame.top3Score)`

Comment: what if newGame was a multidimentional one ?

Comment: the title of the question states `top3Score[0]`, not `top3Score[0,x,...]`

Comment: Sorry, what? if I have `int[][] a`, then `a[0]` is array... `top3Score[0,x,...]` is not Java syntax... Yeah, but maybe from the name `top3Score` it is `int[3]`...

Comment: if you had `topScore[x][y]` then `Arrays.toString(topScore[0])` would work fine, would it not?